# How to properly fit table to page margin?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I have a table that is define as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}}
\hline
 \multirowcell{3}{Work} & \multirowcell{3}{Prime\\[1ex] (bits)} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Area} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Time} \\
 \cline{3-10}
& & \makecell{\# \\FFs} & \makecell{\#\\ LUTs} & \makecell{\#\\ Slices} & \makecell{\# \\ DSPs} & \makecell{\# \\ BRAMs} & \makecell{Freq.\\ (MHz)} & \makecell{Latency \\ (cc${}\times 10^6$)} & \makecell{Total time\\ (ms)} \\
\hline \hline
% Partially removed for brevity
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Comparison of hardware architectures}
\label{tab:hard}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The point is that this works fine and fits the table to my page's margin, but several people here pointed out to me that using `\resizebox` is not recommended and can lead to inconsistent font sizes. Therefore, I would like to hear (and see some examples) as what is a proper way to fit a table to my page's margin? Please also note that I will need to use some footnotes inside the table too.

Comment: Since you can't likely remove enough space to make it fit in portrait mode the best option is make it a sideways table.

Comment: @AlanMunn But using resizebox I get satisfactory result for my case, it’s just that some people pointed out that it is not a good practice. Can I somehow manually change the font size inside the table? I assume that will be a better practice.

Comment: Even changing the fontsize to `\footnotesize` won't give you enough room but that's basically the same strategy as using `\resizebox`. Neither is good, so if the table is too wide and it's not because of obvious things that can be fixed, making the table landscape is the best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting rid of some repetitive material in the header cells and switching to a `tabular*` environment (with `\tabcolsep` set to 0pt) enables you to typeset the material in portrait mode without resorting to the `\resizebox` "hammer". And, for better-spaced horizontal lines, load the `booktabs` package and use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `bottomrule` instead of `\hline` and `\cline`. Finally, if you're at all interested in creating tables with an open or inviting "look", do get rid of all vertical bars -- they're not needed. Really.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out optim. amount of intercol. space
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{10}{c} }
\toprule
 \multirowcell{3}{Work} & 
 \multirowcell{3}{Prime\\[1ex] (bits)} & 
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{Area} & 
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{Time} \\
\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& & \makecell{\# \\FFs} & \makecell{\#\\ LUTs} & \makecell{\#\\ Slices} 
& \makecell{\# \\ DSPs} & \makecell{\# \\ BRAMs} & \makecell{Freq.\\ (MHz)} 
& \makecell{Latency \\ (cc${\times}10^6$)} & \makecell{Total\\ (ms)} \\
\midrule 
\bottomrule
% Partially removed for brevity
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Comparison of hardware architectures}
\label{tab:hard}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say without seeing the table data but this fits the text width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]% never h on it own
\centering
\small\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|*{10}{c|}@{}}
\hline
 \multirowcell{3}{Work} & \multirowcell{3}{Prime\\[1ex] (bits)} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Area} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Time} \\
 \cline{3-10}
& & \makecell{\# \\FFs} & \makecell{\#\\ LUTs} & \makecell{\#\\ Slices} & \makecell{\# \\ DSPs} & \makecell{\# \\ BRAMs} & \makecell{Freq.\\ (MHz)} & \makecell{Latency \\ (cc${}\times 10^6$)} & \makecell{Total\\ (ms)} \\
\hline \hline
% Partially removed for brevity
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of hardware architectures}
\label{tab:hard}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]  Here is an example of using tabularx

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twopage, openright]{memoir}
    \usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx,color}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{enumitem} 
    \usepackage[font={color=black},figurename=Figure., tablename=Table.]{caption}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering, textfont=small}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \centering\small
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison of experimental and predicted fracture energies of CSR particles modified epoxies}
    \label{tab2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
    \hline
    Small CSR       & $\mathrm{\Delta G_s}$  & $\mathrm{\Delta G_v}$         & $\mathrm{\Delta G_v}$    & Predicted   & Predicted    & Experimental \\ 
    (wt\%)  & $\mathrm{J/m^2}$ & $\mathrm{J/m^2}$       & $\mathrm{J/m^2}$          & $\mathrm{G_{IC}}$ $\mathrm{(J/m^2)}$  & $\mathrm{G_{IC}}$ $\mathrm{(J/m^2)}$   & $\mathrm{G_{IC}}$ $\mathrm{(J/m^2)}$ \\ 
            &      &  $\mathrm{r_v}$ measured & $\mathrm{r_v= (1+\gamma_f)r_p}$ &  $\mathrm{r_v}$ measured & $\mathrm{r_v= (1+\gamma_f)r_p}$ &              \\ \midrule
    0           & 0    & 0           & 0             & 78          & 78           & 78 $\pm$ 4       \\ 
    3        & 49   & 123         & 131           & 250         & 258          & 220 $\pm$ 10      \\ 
    6        & 69   & 242         & 258           & 389         & 405          & 430 $\pm$ 12      \\ 
    9         & 81  & 349        & 373          & 508        & 531          & 530 $\pm$ 32      \\ \hline
    Large CSR       & $\mathrm{\Delta G_s}$  & $\mathrm{\Delta G_v}$         & $\mathrm{\Delta G_v}$           & Predicted   & Predicted    & Experimental \\ 
    (wt\%)  & $\mathrm{J/m^2}$ & $\mathrm{J/m^2}$       & $\mathrm{J/m^2}$          & $\mathrm{G_{IC}}$ $\mathrm{(J/m^2)}$  & $\mathrm{G_{IC}}$ $\mathrm{(J/m^2)}$   & $\mathrm{G_{IC}}$ $\mathrm{(J/m^2)}$ \\ 
                  &      &  $\mathrm{r_v}$ measured & $\mathrm{r_v= (1+\gamma_f)r_p}$ & $\mathrm{r_v}$  measured & $\mathrm{r_v= (1+\gamma_f)r_p}$ &              \\ \hline
    0           & 0    & 0           & 0             & 78          & 78           & 78 $\pm$ 4       \\ 
    3       & 49   & 108        & 135           & 235         & 262          & 121 $\pm$ 11      \\ 
    6        & 66   & 196        & 246           & 340         & 389          & 270 $\pm$ 12      \\ 
    9        & 78  & 287      & 360          & 443         & 516         & 403 $\pm$ 32      \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```